# Gardening on a slope

Tags: planting

I have a back yard with a slope, about 25-30 degrees, and there is only a small amount of space that I can garden. What is the best way to garden on a slope?

Comment: How small is "small", and how steep is the slope?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear in the first comment, I only have a small amount of flat land. I would say it is about  25-30 degrees

Comment: Kind of depending on your soil, you can actually garden across that slope (I've done it myself on a 35 deg slope). Is that your intent, or do you only want to put a garden on the flat part? In either case, what kind of soil do you have (clay/not-clay) and what kind of sun exposure do you have?

Comment: please add more details, a diagram with dimensions, where you are located, what you want to use the area for, how much time you want to spend on maintenance, what kind of budget you had in mind

Answer (score 2):

25 degrees is a lot of slope. I have a area that is about 15 degrees ( 4 ' in 20' ). I have timber and rock terraces because anymore than a few degrees will wash away soil. My soil is very sandy so maybe it is worse. I think your decision is "how many terraces ?". I have used patio pavers on edge ; the supply store will have many types and natural flagstone . Also cedar landscape timbers , here they rot away in 20 years. I have done it all myself , one rock or timber at a time is slow but good exercise. After you have terraces think about plants . Although I will mention one attractive ground cover- Bugle weed ( Ajuga reptans ) . It takes zone 5 or 8 , sun or shade ,wet or dry , and spreads. runners tend to hold soil. Basically I am saying you are not going to have much success with your slope , you need terraces.

Comment: Soil type is definitely a concern because you can garden successfully on a slope with loam or clay soils, without terraces but with a good organic mulch (something that doesn't float). I can see how sandy soils would be troublesome and easily wash away, though. My own experience is with clay and loess soils - the  soil washing away wasn't an issue, thankfully. I disagree on the ajuga - it tends to easily get into the lawn and out of control. In shade, I prefer epimedium, ceratostigma (leadwort) or mitchella (partridgeberry); in sun, cerastium (snow in summer) or various sedums.